# The front end works, but the back end doesn't on dotCloud

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, dotcloud

I am creating a real time chat app and have uploaded to dotCloud.
Everything is working fine, but the back end is not working.

Here is my dotcloud app: https://chathouse.dotcloudapp.com/

Also, here is my source code for the chat application. It is very simple. https://github.com/InfamousGamez/chathouse

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I never changed my io.connect to the cloud based website.

:D